# How to compare two columns in Excel using Python?

Tags: python, excel, numpy

I have to excel files with the following fields
**file1**
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9

server1,java_yes,....
server2,java_no,....
server4,java_no,....
server8,java_no,....

**file2**
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9

server1,java_yes,....
server3,java_no,....
server4,java_yes,....
server8,java_no,....

I want to
a. Iterate over file1
b. Compare each entry in col1 in file1 against col1 in file2
c. If it exists, I want to see if the value in file1->col2 matches the entry in file2->col2
d. If file1->col2 does not match file2->col2  then I want to update file1->col2 to equal file2->col2

**Update**

Running in strange issue and providing the details here.
It works fine for most of the entries but for some entries it displays NaN even though the dataframe has java_yes in both places.
To figure this out, I added a filter and then printed it at various stages.
When I print for df1, df2 and merged it works fine.
When I print the same at the very end, it displays NaN for certain entries
Very strange.

```
my_filter = ( df1['col1'] == 'server1' )
print(df1.loc(my_filter, 'col2')
```

All except the last print returns

```
Yes
```

The very last print (for df1) returns

```
NaN
```

Comment: You can use [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: could you provide a minimal example of data for file1-col1 and file2-col2 as well as the expected results? To make sure we understand correctly your question. Looks like you can easily do it using pandas

Comment: Added sample values @thmslmr

Comment: What if col1 value in file1 does not exist in col1 in file2? Should it be left as it is?

Comment: @cottontail  that is correct; file1 is my refence so if a matching entry does not exist in file2 leave it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html):

First, read the files using `pd.read_excel` (or `pd.read_csv`)

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel("path/to/file1.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("path/to/file2.xlsx")
```

From the example you provide, you should have something like that:

df1

|  | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | server1 | java_yes |
| 1 | server2 | java_no |
| 2 | server4 | java_no |
| 3 | server8 | java_no |

df2

|  | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | server1 | java_yes |
| 1 | server3 | java_no |
| 2 | server4 | java_yes |
| 3 | server8 | java_no |

Now merge `df2` into `df1` on `col1` in `left` mode, and overwrite `df1["col2"]` accordingly

```py
merged =  df1.merge(df2, on="col1", how="left")
df1['col2'] = merged['col2_y'].fillna(merged['col2_x'])
```

Resulting `df1` is:

|  | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | server1 | java_yes |
| 1 | server2 | java_no |
| 2 | server4 | java_yes |
| 3 | server8 | java_no |

---

*EDIT: explaining the merge part*

```py
merged =  df1.merge(df2, on="col1", how="left")
```

This line merges `df2` on `df1` based on the values in `"col1"` column.

`how="left"` is used to specify that we want to keep all `col1` values from `df1`, even the ones that don't exist in `df2`. I'll let you check the [DataFrame.merge doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for more details.

The same column names in `df1` and `df2` will be renamed with the default suffix: `_x` and `_y`.

For the rows where the `col1` value does not exist in `df2`, the values in the other columns will be `NaN`.

Here is what `merged` looks like:

|  | col1 | col2_x | col2_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | server1 | java_yes | java_yes |
| 1 | server2 | java_no | nan |
| 2 | server4 | java_no | java_yes |
| 3 | server8 | java_no | java_no |

From here, we want the final `col2` in `df1` to be:

- `col2_y` (ie. `col2` from `df2`) when it's not `NaN` (i.e when `col1` value was in `df2`),
- otherwise `col2_x` (i.e `col2` from `df1`).

In other words, we want `col2_y` after replacing all `NaN` values with the corresponding `col2_x` value. This is what the [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) statement does.

```py
df1['col2'] = merged['col2_y'].fillna(merged['col2_x'])
```

Comment: thmslmr can you explain how that last line works ? I am struggling with understanding the logic.

Comment: @user1074593 I tried to explain a bit more. Tell me if it's ok for you

Comment: thmslmr strange issue. My dataset is not too big (2-4 thousand rows and some 15 columns). The issue I am encountering is that for 40 records it shows that field as NaN. When I printout merged['col_y'] and merged['col2_x'] ; both say the exact same thing "Yes". But when I print the df1['col2'] entry it says NaN. I know this is weird but was checking to see if you had some tips on how to troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi @user1074593. Can you update your question by adding this failing example (minimal data) please ?

Comment: thmslmr added issue as an "update"

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have file called workbook.xlsx containing 2 sheets (i.e. sheet1, sheet2)
firstly you can access it using code like this..

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel("..\workbook.xlsx", sheet_name= "sheet1")
df2 = pd.read_excel("..\workbook.xlsx", sheet_name= "sheet2")
```

now df1 represents the first sheet, df2 represent the second sheet.

you can iterate through df1 on a column name "col1" to check the condition and update your new data frames using this code..

```
for i in range(len(df1["col1"])):
    if (df1["col1"][i] == df2["col1"][i]) and (df1["col2"][i] != df2["col2"][i]):
        df1.at[i,"col2"] = df2["col2"][i]
```

But this will check the associate value on the same row number only.
if you need to check if the Sheet1->col1 value exists in any of Sheet2->col1 values you can use this loop instead will achieve the same result.

```
for i in range(len(df1["col1"])):
    if (df1["col1"][i] in df2["col1"].values):
        j = np.where(df2["col1"] == df1["col1"][i])[0]
        df1.at[i,"col2"] = df2["col2"][j]
```

Finally to store your result into a new excel workbook you can use..

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('New_result.xlsx') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1")
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet2")
```

This will guarantee you to match all values from Sheet1->col2 with Sheet2->col2 as long as Sheet1->col1 == Sheet2->col1

Comment: Sheet1->col1 will not always match Sheet2->col1; this is where I am struggling because the only way to do this is to iterate over the entire "Sheet2->col1" for every single entry in "Sheet1->col1" and that takes forever.

Comment: Ok I got you now, I've updated the answer to fit your question.